# Detecting colored objects on a image which contains a dark background

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, detection, contour

I'm currently using OpenCV to try to detect objects on a black cloth covered table. The camera will not always be looking at the same direction (it's a robot's head) but only one image will be processed, so speed is not an imperative. I haved used `cv::Canny` and `cv::findContours` with the most adequate parameters I could find, before removing contours which have a too small area. This gets me close to the result I want but some contours which are not in the table area are obviously detected.
What would be a good way to filter those ? 
I was thinking of three solutions (which could be combined for better results) :

- Cropping the image to just keep the table area, but I can't think of a good criteria (`cv::HoughLines` ?).
- Removing contours which are not closed. This does not limit itself to convex contours (the orange dolphin on the right is not, for instance). Would checking the distance between the first `cv::Point` and the last `cv::Point` in the contour (which is a `vector<cv::Point>`) work ?
- Studying a circle a few pixels outside of each contour and check the HSV channels to find out if all pixels of the circle are dark enough to be considered as part of the table.

If anyone has an efficient way to filter those contours, or just input and advice about one of the filtering methods above, it would be just great. Also the robot hand you can see on the bottom right will not be an issue because they will be out of the field of view during the real experiment.

[image: Image from the camera to be processed]

Comment: You will get better help if you [post your code](http://sscce.org) so others can reproduce your results and offer improvements.

Comment: I think this is not a programming question but a research question. Without knowing your research environment such as light condition, type of objects to detect or not, there is no way for us to answer the question. Even with the knowledge, answering the question typically involves image data analysis.

Comment: In my opinion, it qualifies as programming as well. I was mostly looking for some people who might have used one of OpenCV functions to do that kind of work. I will post the code on Monday since I have no access to the computer in question.